# What is callback url in instagram api and how to can I implement it

Tags: api, callback, oauth-2.0, instagram

Hi I'm beginner programmer

I'm trying to use instagram's realtime Photo Updates api

My purpose is use this API CONSOLE's subscription method 
https://apigee.com/console/instagram

But I can't understand and handle callback url

What is the callback url's function?

And How can I implement the callback url?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "callback url" (also referred to as `redirect_url`), is the URL Instagram will send users to **after** they have logged into Instagram, and authorized your application to read their data.

This is part of the [OAuth 2 Spec](http://oauth.net/2/), which Instagram (and many others) use to control access to their API.

The short version of the OAuth 2 "flow" is this:

- You send a user to Instagram's page with your application ID, and a redirect URL.
- The user logs into Instagram on their page and authorizes your application.
- Instagram will then send the user back to your application (using the redirect URL value), along with a token that you can use to access their data.

GitHub has an [excellent guide](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) to how OAuth works on their server, which you will find very similar to Instagram's.

---

So the "callback url" should be set to the URL of your application server. For example, `http://myapp.com/auth`. Or, if you are working locally, you would use `http://localhost:3000/auth`.

**Note:** With Instagram (as well as most other APIs), the callback URL is permanently set when you register your client. So you'll often have to create separate clients for your live server, and your local one.