# How to get response data from the Safari url in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, url, safari

I want to do Instagram login in the Safari and want response of it in the ios app.

I have redirected to Safari for Instagram login from the iPhone app.
Now I want to get response data of that Instagram login of Safari in the iPhone app.

I have no idea about it. So is this possible? Can we get response of Safari URL in the iOS app?

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391359/what-is-callback-url-in-instagram-api-and-how-to-can-i-implement-it

Answer (score 1):

For that you would have to use UIWebView and its delegate methods.

Code from [Instagram-Auth-iOS](https://github.com/Buza/Instagram-Auth-iOS/blob/master/Instagram-Auth-iOS/InstagramAuthenticatorView.m)

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *responseURL = [request.URL absoluteString];

    NSString *urlCallbackPrefix = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/?code=", INSTAGRAM_CALLBACK_BASE];

    //We received the code, now request the auth token from Instagram.
    if([responseURL hasPrefix:urlCallbackPrefix])
    {
        NSString *authToken = [responseURL substringFromIndex:[urlCallbackPrefix length]];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

        NSDictionary *paramDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:authToken, @"code", INSTAGRAM_CALLBACK_BASE, @"redirect_uri", @"authorization_code", @"grant_type",  INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID, @"client_id",  INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET, @"client_secret", nil];

        NSString *paramString = [paramDict urlEncodedString];

        NSString *charset = (NSString *)CFStringConvertEncodingToIANACharSetName(CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=%@",charset] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:[paramString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        self.tokenRequestConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        [self.tokenRequestConnection start];

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

This repo on Github [Instagram-Auth-iOS](https://github.com/Buza/Instagram-Auth-iOS) will help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i want to do this in Safari instead of WebView. Can I ?