# What is a callback url for an API and when and how do you use one in python

Tags: callbackurl, x-callback-url

I am using an API and it asks for a "callback url". What is a "callback url" and when and how do you set one up in Python

Comment: Please check this question. It explains beautifully, what actually is callback URL
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347056/what-is-a-callback-url-in-relation-to-an-api

Answer (score 3):

A callback URL is used similarly to a callback function if you have any experience with them. Essentially, when you call an API and provide a callback URL, when that API finishes, it will redirect the user to said callback URL.

A great example is in third-party authentication services. When a user goes down the route of logging in through the third-party, you call their API and provide them that callback url so that once they verify the user, they can direct them into your application.

As for telling you how to set one up, there's no way for us to give you a generic guide aside from what I just outlined. If you need anything more than that, please provide the relative portions of the codebase that you are working on.